# get value from array Multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I have file.csv like this:

```
Name , Gender , Age   //header
John , M      , 22
Jack , M      , 20
```

I read it and store in array so I try this:

```
$fileName = "file.csv";
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));
```

And this gave me an array like this:

```
Array   [0] => 
              Array ( [0] => Name [1] => Gender [2] => Age)
        [1]=> 
              Array ( [0] => John [1] => M      [2] => 22 )
        [2]=> 
              Array ( [0] => Jack [1] => M      [2] => 20 )
```

This is so simple but im sorry I don't know how :'(
I want to get only the Age value from each person (not include header) for parameters in my **function countAge($age)**. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the first element of array with `array_shift()` and then iterate with foreach like this:

```
array_shift( $array );

foreach( $array as $a )
{
    if ( isset( $a[2] ) )
    {
        $age = $a[2]; // $a[2] has the age value
        echo "Age: " . $age;
    }
}
```

or you can iterate through the array with a for loop starting from second element:

```
for( $i = 1 ; $i < count( $array ) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset( $array[$i][ 2 ] ) )
    {
        $age = $array[$i][2];
        echo "Age: " . $age;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but somehow, in the middle of process, Im getting error msg "undefined offset 2"

Comment: @jill182 Sounds like there are rows without age value in your csv file. Can you check it?

Comment: im sure all rows have age value. Actually I have 200 row, but when i count array it contains 200++. Maybe there's something wrong when I convert csv to array?

Comment: That might be the case. Can you control it with var_dump ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly this should do it:

```
for( $i = 1; $i < sizeof($array); $i++ ) {
  if( isset( $array[$i][2] ) ) {
    $age = $array[$i][2];
    // Further use $age as you need it.
  }
}
```

Comment: it works but somehow, in the middle of process, Im getting error msg "undefined offset 2"

Comment: Maybe you don't have the age set for some people. I'll update my answer to check if the age is set.